# Cannot read cyrillic symbols from a .csv file

Tags: node.js, json, csv, encoding, cyrillic

I need to read some `.csv` file, get data in `.json` format and work with it.
I'm using npm package [convert-csv-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json). As a result - cyrillic symbols aren't displaying properly:

```
const csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json');

let json = csvToJson.fieldDelimiter(',').getJsonFromCsv("input.csv");
console.log(json);
```

Result:

[image]

If I try to decode file:

```
const csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json');

let json = csvToJson.asciiEncoding().fieldDelimiter(',').getJsonFromCsv("input.csv");
console.log(json);
```

result is:

[image]

When I open a `.csv` file using `AkelPad` or `notepad++` - it displays as it has to, and detected format is `Win 1251 (ANSI - кириллица)`.
Is there a way to read a file with properly encoding, or to decode a result string?

Comment: I would look at [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite). Iconv handles pretty much every standard.

Comment: Scroll down to https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json#encoding in your docs (it appears that `Win 1251` isn't supported). Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: @MyICQ ok, iconv-lite works in my case. But I have a string as a result, and I need an array of objects. Can you suggest some easy way to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code to solve the problem:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
    const Papa = require('papaparse');

    // read csv file and get buffer
    const buffer = fs.readFileSync("input.csv");
    
    // parse buffer to string with encoding
    let dataString = iconv.decode(buffer, 'win1251');   
    
    // parse string to array of objects
    let config = {
        header: true
    };
    const parsedOutput = Papa.parse(dataString, config);
    console.log('parsedOutput: ', parsedOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII.

As a result, change

```
let json = csvToJson.asciiEncoding().fieldDelimiter(',').getJsonFromCsv("input.csv");
```

to

```
let json = csvToJson.utf8Encoding().fieldDelimiter(',').getJsonFromCsv("input.csv");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as well, just another gibberish as result